# Problem with python script and relative import

Tags: python

Im starting with Python and I try to run one simple app which worked for me few months ago in different test env (both ubuntu), but I receive an error I could not found an understandeable solution on google/stackoverflow.

```
[root@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/appname# python3 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    from appname import AppName
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/appname/appname.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import __version__
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I have the **version** variable defined in **init**.py, but its not imported. When I comment (#) this import/variable in appname.py I receive another import error with relative path from files which are in the same folder and appname.py, like

```
from .test import anyfunction
```

where test.py is in the same folder as appname.py

Do you have any idea why this import with relative path does not work?

Thank you and sorry if this is stupid question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to the problem you are describing, but have you tried putting __init__.py file in the folders in question?

Comment: Have you installed this package in your existing env? Check if its there in ur venv if ur using one. If not check the global libraries...

Comment: @MinhNguyen all of the questioned files are in one folder. Thats why its weird

Comment: @leoOrion its installed in the global env. I will try to do that in venv tho.

Comment: I installed it in venv, still the same issue, like it does not know where the "HOME" is even its in the same folder

Comment: Can u try importing this in the python repl first. Try various combinations to see which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution by running the "app" in VENV and also upgrading the SETUPTOOLS to the latest version. It looks like there was just conflict in modules inside the app.